# How to test InternalServerError in xUnit for .NET 6 Web API

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-6.0, xunit, webapi

I have below unit test case and I want to perform a test for 500 - internal serve error. I am stuck with what to compare it so that it will passed.

```
    [Fact]
        public async Task ShouldReturnInternalServerError_OnUnhandledError()
        {
        //arrange
            var Id = fixure.Create<string>();
            List<Emp> emps = fixure.Create<List<Emp>>();
            var exception = new Exception("Internal Server Error");

            factsService.Setup(x => x.SetEmps(Id,emps)).Throws(exception);

            //act
            var response = await EmpController.SetEmps(Id, emps);

            //assert
            response.Should().NotBeNull();
            response.Should().BeAssignableTo<ActionResult>();

           //this is for bad request 
           //response.Should().BeAssignableTo<BadRequestObjectResult>();
           //not sure what to match here below for InternalServerError
            response.Should().
}
```

Comment: What is `EmpController.SetEmps`? And why are you **expecting** HTTP 500? a HTTP 500 _should never happen_ in the first place, so there's no reason to write a test for it...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with such unit test, you need to use [integration test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0) approach. For this approach you can only check that `EmpController.SetEmps` throws a correct exception (i.e. `EmpController.Invoking(y => y.SetEmps(Id, emps).Should().Throw<...>().WithMessage(...)`). Controller actions/methods  do not perform any magic to handle unhandled exceptions, it is done "later" down the pipeline.

Also note that possibly unit testing for HTTP 500 is kind of pointless.